# Show $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}(|c+\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}}|-|c|) = d* sign(c)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, absolute-value

Consider the sequence of real numbers $\sqrt{n}\left(\left|c+\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}}\right|-|c|\right)$ with $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c\neq 0$. Could you help me to show that

$$\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}\left( \left| c+\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}}\right|-|c|\right) = d\cdot\text{sign}(c)$$

where $\text{sign}(\cdot)$ is the sign (or signum) function defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).  I don't understand what about the case in which $c+\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}}\geq 0$ and $c<0$. Do I need other conditions to establish the result?

Comment: Do you mean signum function?

Comment: I have edited the question thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach than in [user296113's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1658326/75808):

$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\left\lvert c+\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}}\right\rvert - \lvert c\rvert\right)
=\lvert c\rvert \sqrt{n}\left(\left\lvert 1+\frac{d}{c\sqrt{n}}\right\rvert - 1\right)
$$
since $\frac{d}{c\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, we have $1+\frac{d}{c\sqrt{n}} > 0$ for $n$ large enough, and then we get
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\left\lvert c+\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}}\right\rvert - \lvert c\rvert\right)
=\lvert c\rvert \sqrt{n}\left( 1+\frac{d}{c\sqrt{n}} - 1\right)
=\lvert c\rvert \sqrt{n}\frac{d}{c\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\lvert c\rvert}{c}d = \operatorname{sign}(c)d.
$$

Note that this means the quantity not only *converges* to $\operatorname{sign}(c)d$, but is actually *equal* to it for $n$ big enough. (There exists $N=N(c,d)\geq 1$ such that, for all $n\geq N$, we have equality.)

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by the conjugate you get

$$\frac{2cd+\frac{d^2}{\sqrt n}}{\left|c+\frac d{\sqrt n}\right|+|c|}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac{c}{|c|}d$$

Answer (score 1):

For $n\gg 0$, $|\frac d{\sqrt n}|<|c|$ and hence $\operatorname{sgn}(c+\frac d{\sqrt n})=\operatorname{sgn}(c)$.
So for such $n$
$$ \begin{align}\sqrt n\left(\bigl|c+\tfrac d{\sqrt n}\bigr|-|c|\right)&=\sqrt n\left(\bigl(c+\tfrac d{\sqrt n}\bigr)\cdot \operatorname{sgn}\bigl(c+\tfrac d{\sqrt n}\bigr)-c\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(c)\right)
\\&=\sqrt n\left(\bigl(c+\tfrac d{\sqrt n}\bigr)\cdot \operatorname{sgn}(c)-c\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(c)\right)\\
&=\sqrt n\cdot\bigl(c+\tfrac d{\sqrt n}-c\bigr)\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(c)\\
&=d\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(c)\end{align}$$